# merging sheets with same name skipping files without that sheet and adding column with the file's name

Tags: r

i am quite new in R, so please don't be hangry if my question is quite stupid for you :)

Basically, I have different .xlsx file in a folder with the same structure in terms of sheets, but in some cases the same sheet is not present in all the files.

While when the sheet is always present, I run the code below, adding a column with the name of the file:

```r
library(readxl)
library(tidyr)
myfiles<-list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx")
myfiles
test = lapply (myfiles, function(i){
x = read_excel(i, sheet='sheet_1')  
    x$file = i
    x
})
```

when the sheet is not present in all the files the code above does not work, detecting error due to missing sheet. I run the code below, but i dont manage to add the columun with the name of the file, as i manage above.

```r
library(readxl)
library(tidyr)
all_files <- list.files(pattern = '*.xlsx')
result <- lapply(all_files, function(x) {
    all_sheets <- excel_sheets(x)  
    correct_sheet <- intersect(all_sheets, c('Sheet_2’)
    if(length(correct_sheet)) read.xlsx(x,correct_sheet)
})
prova<-do.call(rbind, result)
```

Someone could help me?? thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Use `length(correct_sheet)==0` or `"Sheet_2" %in% all_sheets`. 0 or 1 does not work in conditions.

Comment: I don't catch the point. Using this how can I have the name of the file's within the dB? Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code. The line `correct_sheet <- intersect(all_sheets, c('Sheet_2’)`  needs an extra closing bracket. Did that happen when you stripped down the code to a minimal reproducible example or is it in the actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `try()`.

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyr)


myfiles<-list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx")

test = lapply (myfiles, function(i) try({
x = read_excel(i, sheet='sheet_1')  
x$file = i
x
},silent=TRUE))
```

Here, the `try()` function is used because it stops your code from quitting and throwing an error when it hits one.  It'll look through the files and "try" to do as you're hoping. I use `silent=TRUE` when I don't want the error log that you get if you accept the default setting.

From there, you'll see that your list has some funky items with error-related text, but also that the data from the sheets you specified is coming through.  If you want to get to only the data from the sheets you've successfully pulled data in from, you can do something like:

```
test<-Filter(function(x) is.tbl(x),test)
```

What you're doing here is taking advantage of the `Filter()` function, and filtering `test` down so that only the tibbles pulled from the sheets in your excel files are preserved.

Optionally, if you want to get all your data into a single tibble, I suggest using `bind_rows()`

```
test<-bind_rows(test)
```